# When using Hibernate for Java getting abnormal behavior binding parameterList in HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, where-in

**UPDATE**
I found the issue. Kind of embarrassing. The client side code was sending a `Set` of 1 element which was the concatenated String of the report Ids. AArgh!

---

I am using hibernate v3.6.4 in my Java project. I am getting problems when trying to use a parameter list for a named parameter in my HQL query.

Basically I want to get all the records which match one of the "`id`"s mentioned in the `IN` clause.

I tried using both HQL & Criteria I get the same result.

My HQL query,

```
Set<String> reportIds = new HashSet<String>();
reportIds.add("1");
reportIds.add("2");

String whereClause = "from Report where id IN (:reportIds) ";
Query query = session.createQuery(whereClause);
query.setParameterList("reportIds", reportIds);
```

Output = empty list. Although I checked by firing manual sql queries in the terminal that there are indeed such records.

I turned on the logging and here is what I see,

```
Hibernate: 
    /* 
from
    Report 
where
    id IN (
        :ids
    ) */ select
        mediavalue0_.id as id31_,
        ...

    from
        report mediavalue0_ 
    where
        mediavalue0_.id in (
            ?
        )
HibernateLog --> 13:22:36 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - 1,2
```

This is very abnormal because if you notice the final bind statement it considers the toString of the Set! i.e. "1,2" instead of "1" and then "2"!

I was messing around with it so on a whim I decided to directly create the instance of the set inside the `setParameterList` method call itself. Like so,

```
query.setParameterList("reportIds", Sets.newHashSet("1","2"));
```

And it worked! BTW Sets.newHashSet is a construct provided google's guava library. I use the same library to generate the original reportIds set. So there is no inconsistency there.

This query translates to following TRACE,

```
from
    Report 
where
    id IN (
        :ids
    ) */ select
        mediavalue0_.id as id31_,
        ...
    from
        report mediavalue0_ 
    where
        mediavalue0_.id in (
            ? , ?
        )
HibernateLog --> 13:28:57 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - 1
HibernateLog --> 13:28:57 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - 2
```

Notice the separate binds for VARCHAR.

I am totally flummoxed by this odd behavior. Maybe some of you guys can point out what I am doing wrong.

FYI the criteria construct I used (& which resulted in the same output) is like so,

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Report.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", reportIds));
```

P.S. I also used a named sql query with same result

```
<sql-query name="reportByIds">
    <return class="report.Report"/>
    SELECT mvr.* from report mvr
    WHERE mvr.id IN :ids
</sql-query>
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to step into the setParameterList method?  It would be interesting to make sure that it stepped into the same method implementation in both scenarios, vs. stepping into setParameterList(String, Object) in the first scenario and setParameterList(String, Collection) in the second.

Comment: @mattforsythe Actually I found out the my client side code, which was feeding report ids was faulty. When it encountered an array it did not properly serialize it. This resulted in a Set of 1 element which was concetenated string of report ids.

Comment: But in the question you stated that a set contains two elements of type `String`.

Comment: @RomanC I did not do enough checking, to make sure that it ACTUALLY had 2 elements. I just trusted my server side code that deserialized the client sent array.

Answer (score 0):

Assume id attribute is of type `Long`

```
Set<Long> reportIds = new HashSet<Long>();
reportIds.add(1l);
reportIds.add(2l);
```

then the query should work, the criteria also works